Colorbox - force screen to landscape on mobile device
I am using colorbox to play audio when user click on Play button on parent page.
I want to force screen orientation to landscape on Mobile Devices when colorbox opens.
currently code to open colorbox is as follow :
$(document).on("click", ".colorbox-my", function(){     
    $.colorbox({
        href: $(this).data('url'),
        iframe: true,
        innerWidth: '95%',
        innerHeight:'70%',
        opacity : 0,
        fixed:true, 
        escKey: false, 
        overlayClose: false,   
        
         onOpen: function() {
          $('#cboxOverlay,#colorbox').css('visibility', 'hidden');
          $('#cboxOverlay').css({
             'visibility': 'visible',
             'opacity': 0.9,
             'cursor': 'pointer'            
          }).animate({
             height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
             opacity: 'toggle'
          }, 100 , function() {
          $('#colorbox').css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
          }).fadeIn(300);
       });
    }
   });
 });    

I currently tried following code to page which is opening in colorbox
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape)
  and (min-device-width: 319px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px) 
  and (max-device-width: 768px) {
   body {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;

   }
}

